# Selenium Remote Webdriver not working with AWS EC2

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to do some website testing which requires to keep the old webdriver open then use webdriver.remote to re-attach back using the executor url and session id of the old driver. Same code runs fine on my MacBook, but running into error on AWS EC2 Ubuntu 16.04. Error Trace back and code are attached below. Please help.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Selenium Version: 3.4.0

Browser: Google-Chrome

[image][image]

[image: New Code following @Tarun Lalwani's Idea]

Comment: The default Ubuntu installation doesn't have a windowing system installed.  Have you installed a windowing system and Chrome?

Comment: @stdunbar Since it's a AWS EC2 instance, there is no GUI. I run code through terminal and also have set up the webdriver being headless. Not sure if installing windowing system will help.

Comment: Without a GUI Chrome can't run.  Headless just means that there isn't a monitor attached.

Comment: @stdunbar Still a little bit confused here. I was able to create the Webdriver.Chrome and ChromeDriver was able to reach whatever urls I pointed. If you comment out the driver2 part of my code, everything runs.

Comment: I would suggest try ghost browser or phantomJS driver as there is no GUI.

Comment: Your code to re-connect the session is wrong. You launch a non-headless browser the 2nd time and then close it. It will work fine in case of your Mac because the other browser will launch but on AWS it won't. You need to use the technique I described in my article http://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium/ to reconnect to the existing session

Comment: I think we are missing some things here - the stacktrace is for Save.py, but your code is Test.py? Anyhow, you have closed driver2 at line 21, so trying to do get() after would fail.

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani  I actually got the idea from your blog. The reason why I close the driver2 is because driver2.remote launch a new Chrome Driver which is no used from we attach driver2 back to driver using Session ID and executor_url.

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani I tried to use your original code from your blog, still getting Chrome failed to start error. And the error showed the first driver (driver = webdriver.Chrome() ) cannot even start.

Comment: @HaC My apologies. I just have the same code on 2 different files. I've edited the post. Also, see comments about driver2.close() above.

Comment: You need to set the chrome options like you did originally so that it is a headless browser

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani Do you mean add headless to webdriver.remote?

Comment: I mean launch the first driver using your original code

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani Never mind, got it working. Turns out need to add chrome_options to webdriver.Remote.

Answer (score 2):

After digging so long for this issue, I finally found the solution myself. Turns out Ubuntu without GUI is pain in the butt to deal with. So when you try to launch Selenium Webdriver. You need to add a few options not only the regular webdriver.Chrome, but also webdriver.Remote.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import 
DesiredCapabilities

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
executor_url = driver.command_executor._url
session_id = driver.session_id
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

print(session_id)
print(executor_url)

print(driver.current_url)

driver2 = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=executor_url, desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())
driver2.close()
driver2.session_id = session_id
print(driver2.current_url)
driver2.get("http://www.facebook.com")
print(driver2.current_url)
```

Also, having webdriver.remote will open up a zombie webdriver too. If you only care about re attach back to existing webdriver. You can close the new driver before the new driver attached back to the old one.